# Autofac can't resolve HTTPContext parameter while the correct module is present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, httpcontext

So I'm using Autofac as a DI framework and MVC5. One of my service classes has HttpContext as a parameter so I'm registering the `Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacWebTypesModule` as it suggests [here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#register-web-abstractions)

I *was* getting an error message in Visual Studio itself which after closing Visual Studio and re-opening has gone away. However, I am still getting the same message when loading up the site:

`Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Web.HttpContext httpContext' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Web.HttpContext)'.`

**Edit:** Updated with the full path to the classes

Comment: Where does your `AutofacWebTypesModule` came from ? normally it should come from the *Autofac.Integration.Mvc* assembly. Is it the case ?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the "red line in Visual Studio" you are speaking about ?

Comment: No because I'm not getting the same error message anymore. I'm still getting a 500 on the web page. Let me update the text of the question...

Comment: You're trying to inject the `HttpContext` into a component that isn't in the right scope.  How are you registering this component?  How are you resolving it?  You shouldn't have any problems injecting `HttpContext` into one of your MVC controllers, assuming they were registered correctly.

Comment: When You resolve your component do You have an active httpcontext : does the resolution process follow a http request ? What is the callstack of the error ?

Answer (score 0):

AutofacWebTypesModule register only HttpContextBase and not HttpContext and they are not bounded with inheritance hierarchy. Instead of HttpContext accept HttpContextBase type parameter in your controller constructor.